# Chi-squared Test in Kalman Filter

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared, kalman-filter

I have designed a Kalman filter which has 2 models.

For switching between models in the Kalman filter, I want to use a Chi-squared $ χ^2 $ test based on the **innovation**
$ ν(k) $
of the Kalman filter, which **k** is step time.

Apparently, I should use normalized innovation squared (NIS)

$ NIS = ν(k)^T * [H_kP^-P^T+R] * ν(k)  $

in a hypothesis test. It should be compared with a threshold
$χ^2_U$
that has a standard table ( Based on Degree of freedom and significance level ). Also, I use the $Chi2inv()$ command in MATLAB for the calculation of the threshold.

If   **$NIS>χ^2_U$** ,  the first model is rejected and I should switch to another model.

But my $NIS$ value is always less than $χ^2_U$ because $NIS<10^{-20}$, which makes it impossible to use the Chi-squared test.

How should I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your notation, it could be correct but is of a form I haven't seen before. You could try using the NIS formulation given by Bar-Shalom in *Estimation with Applications to Tracking and Navigation: Theory Algorithms and Software*.

There, the NIS parameter should equal $e^T_{z,k}P^{-1}_{k|k}e_{z,k}$. Where the measurement innovation $e_{z,k}$ is defined as $e_{z,k} = z_k - H\hat{x}_{k|k-1}$. $P_{k|k}$ is the estimate covariance, $z_k$ is the measurement vector, $H$ is the observation matrix, and $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ is the a priori state estimate.

You should consider using both the upper and lower $\chi^2$ bounds by the way, since $NIS < \chi^2_{lower}$ could indicate that your filter is behaving overly conservatively and is perhaps overly-tuned or that your process or measurement noises are inappropriately sized.